# SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat7, windows-7-x64

I have done loads of research on this issue and tried everything I found to make it work to no avail.

I am developing a Java application on my Windows PC running tomcat 7.

I have used the following command to install the cert

```
keytool -import -alias srv03wpayco -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file srv03.wpay.co.crt
```

And tried the same in the

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\lib\security\cacerts
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\security\cacerts
```

folders.

I have made sure the tomcat configured in MyEclipse is using the java path

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
```

through Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

and added the Default VM arguments

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

I am running tomcat from the myEclipse IDE and still get the exception

```
SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Can somebody please help? I am at my wit's end and have no clue what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [SSL Labs SSL scan report for srv03.wpay.co](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=srv03.wpay.co), you are not sending an intermediate certificate.

[image: SSL Labs report showing incomplete chain].

Can you give it a try after you add this intermediate cert? You can obtain it from https://whatsmychaincert.com/?srv03.wpay.co

Also, while you're at it, consider addressing the numerous vulnerabilities and weaknesses with the server's SSL configuration as reported by SSL Labs.

Comment: you're a star! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try keytool -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -importcert -alias srv03wpayco -file srv03.wpay.co.crt

Comment: i delete the cacerts i had there to make sure I don't get any interference and ran the command you send but it still did not work.

Comment: type the command keytool -list -keystore cacerts and verify if your certificate is present.

Comment: My certificate is there, could it be a config of my Environment Variables?